# Scrollable set of elements in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a set of items in ItemsControl. I am displaying all of them but I want to make visible only a subset of items. So I kind of want to specify the visible area of ItemsControl (or any other element which supports this). Other elements could be seen after scrolling is applied.

I could do it on ViewModel-side and pass to ItemsControl only visible elements but I am interested in View-only solution. Is there any?

Comment: Why not use a ListBox? It already supports scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `ScrollViewer` in your `ItemsControl`'s style, then if your items will overflow the width or height of the `ItemsControl` a ScrollBar will appear.

```
<Style x:Key="ItemsControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```